# Why do I get this null pointer exception?

Tags: android, java

When I execute this code it gives me the Exception Glthread 8 Java.lang.null.pointer

```
MouseJointDef md = new MouseJointDef();  
md.bodyA = _body;
md.bodyB = _body;
md.target.set(locationWorld);
md.collideConnected = true;
md.maxForce = 1000.0f * _body.getMass();

_mouseJoint =  (MouseJoint) _world.createJoint(md);
_body.setAwake(true);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which line exactly?

Comment: Body A and B are the same for the joint? You sure that makes sense?

Comment: Voted to close as too localized. Make use of the debugger?

Comment: sorry for that the body b is _paddlebody

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger to see which variable is null?

Comment: GDSE is *not* a debugger

Comment: Which line? What is the stacktrace?

Answer (score 5):

This is a case of "give a man a fish/teach a man to fish". You should learn to use the debugger to figure this problem out yourself.

Here is a good place to start:

http://www.infinitezest.com/articles/debugging-an-android-application.aspx

and you can find more here:

[the google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=android%20debugger)

FWIW as your code stands, the most likely perpetrator are `md.target`, `_body` and `_world`.